# Ubuntu 15.04 Kilo install

Tags: 15.04, maas, openstack

I have looked at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack for installing OpenStack Kilo with 15.04.

1. First, the so-called [reference architecture](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack/reference-architecture) is of little help. It should talk about why 7 servers are required and what their roles are, and also the networking requirements. Is there a real reference document anywhere?
2. Can I install MAAS controller and OpenStack controller on the same host?

Answer (score 0):

Good job for checking in here for a sanity check before just installing.  You shouldn't need a ton of servers for the minimum setup--I've put nearly everything on just three servers before:  1) MaaS plus juju, 2) all charms except nova-compute, 3) nova-compute.  And you then can scale out nova-compute onto more servers if you'd like.

Given that you might be doing this over and over and over again I would recommend not adding anything in the way of charms to your MaaS controller.  In fact, I'm not sure if you could if you wanted to.  MaaS will enlist other servers and apply an image to them.  With a single checkbox somewhere in the setup it will even erase the entire hard drive so it would be a bad idea to try to enlist the MaaS server itself.

What's important to note in the way of documentation is that you'll find the OpenStack documentation not only on www.Ubuntu.com but also on help.ubuntu.com, OpenStack.org and jujucharms.com.

Starting from [this jujucharms URL](https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/), I was able to download their bundle.yaml file and edit it for my own needs.  Theirs assumes a four-server install (which will save you a couple of servers from the version you're trying to use).  Additionally, this approach uses the "juju quickstart..." syntax instead of the "juju bootstrap..." plus "juju deploy..." collective syntax.  Things will happen a lot faster and simpler, in other words.

The upside to juju quickstart is that everything seems to work better.  The downside to juju quickstart is that you don't run each command individually so you know a little less about what's going on.

If you don't want to use a charms bundle for OpenStack itself and like the idea of juju bootstrap, then check out [this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Installing-OpenStack.html) especially at Appendix I for an economic deployment.  But be careful about what version of OpenStack that you pull.  By default you might not get Kilo like you would using the bundle approach above.

[image: This is likely what you're looking for]